# How can Telerik OpenAccess ORM be used in partnership with TFS?

Tags: version-control, orm, tfs, telerik, telerik-open-access

In a number of team projects I've worked on over the past year, we have chosen the Telerik OpenAccess ORM as the tool to manage our database model. We also use TFS as our version control software

I've ran into a number of difficulties using the Telerik product (which I'll save for another day), but one of the biggest issues is when multiple team members attempt to work on the model simultaneously, and try to commit their changes to TFS. The models generated by Telerik are difficult to merge and any conflicts will, more often than not, lead to time lost fixing the entity model. The only practical way to avoid these difficulties seems to be to implement a "relay" system, where only one person at a time can work with the model; something that isn't practical in a team development environment.

Has anyone found a way to use the two tools harmoniously?

Comment: My favourite approach to this is to use Entity framework code first migrations and let the developers avoid touching the model all together. If you need a model to print out and stick on the wall, let the dba maintain this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Answer (score 4):

This will always be an issue when working with similar models, even the model used by the Entity Framework.

You could always switch to Code Only mappings though. Then all of the mapping for your project will be simple, merge-able code files.  [link](http://documentation.telerik.com/openaccess-orm/developers-guide/code-only-mapping/fluent-mapping-overview)